# How to connect real world data with OPC UA Server

Tags: c#, web, service, opc

i am working with the Unified Automation OPC UA C# SDK. I have done all the Tutorials and read the Documents. I can not finde any hints about how to get data from a machine tool or web service. Can someone help me, please.

Best Regards
S.Tek

Comment: Your question is not very clear, please clarify your question. Are you developing an OPC UA client or OPC UA Server? If you are developing a client are you simply looking for a test server to test the client on. If you are developing a server what exactly are you trying to communicate with?

Comment: I am developing an OPC UA Server for machine tools. But i dont know how to get the data from real world machines. In every sample there is a simulator in the code who simulates the data values. But no sample who connects to a thing outside of the code.

Comment: What protocols are support by your equipment? You typically connect to the equipment via a standard TCP/IP socket if the equipment support network communications.  However, the communications may be handled differently from equipment to equipment depending on what protocol is support. Example some equipment may use Modbus while others use AK protocol.  
If you intend to communication to equipment via known standard such as Modbus or MTConnect I would simply buy an of the shelf OPC server.

Comment: My equipment supports Siemens, Bosch, Heidenhain and Fanuc. But we have a Adapter which combines all this in Webservice. From there i can use the links from diffined methods to send data of axes etc. with xml or json.

Comment: Are you sure your adaptor does not support the MTConnect standard? If it does I would read the following  http://www.automation.com/pdf_articles/gettingstartedwithmtconnectwritingclientsrevisionjuly2013.pdf
If this is a custom web services, then you will have to add a web reference to your visual studio project. VS will create all the necessary interfaces for you. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am going to write a web service and get the machine data in jason from web service. i hope i will success

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for somtething like this

https://fistfulofbytes.com/opc-sample-code

Comment: I have looked at it but that isnt the sample i am searching for.